# Yii2 access to module instance from model

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-module

I want to know if there is a way to access at the module instance from a model. In my module configuration I have some components which I need to call in a model class, the model is defined only inside my module. I know the method `Yii::$app->getModule('my-module')` but this mean that the module have to be defined every time with the same name, from controller's module I can access as `$this->module->component-name`, something similar in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access the module instance like this:

```
$module = MyModuleClass::getInstance();
```

Then you can get id via

```
$module->id
```

For more information check [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html)

Comment: Did you check this? @MarBer

Comment: Yes thanks for the rapid answer and for the edit (today is monday!)

Comment: glad to help you @MarBer

Comment: @MarBer Bizley provided right answer, lalith provided wrong answer and just copied right one from Bizley and edit his, that's just not nice...

Comment: @lalithkumar - i see edit history and time of adding answer. Please don't lie.

Comment: I choose lalithkumar answer because he edit my question before answer, the answer, if we ignore the edit, are the same. How we can resolve this? Sorry @Bizley for not choose your answer but I have consider, like I write above, the edit work done by lalithkumar, if I can do something...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ModelClassName::getInstance()` but right now it works only when module has been already initialized. This should be changed around [2.0.15](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/14421).

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer and sorry for the dispute!